# Metric space and closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ have a Euclidian metric $d$ and $\emptyset \neq A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a subset such that $(A, d_{|A \times A})$ is a metric space.

(a) Let $x \in A$ and consider the set $D := \{y \in A: d(x, y) \geq r\}$. Is $D$ closed in $A$?

(b) Let $x \in A$ and consider the set $E := \{y \in A: d(x, y) > r\}$. Is $D$ contained in the closure of $E$ in $A$?

Justify your answers.

I am reviewing solutions to various problems for an upcoming examination and this was a problem in a practice set but there are no solutions available. Any assistance with a solution is much appreciated.

Comment: $D$ is closed and the closure of $E$ is contained in $D$, and in the case of $\Bbb R^n$ actually equal to it, in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be in $A$. We have

$D^c=\{y\in A, d(x,y)<r\}=B(x,r)$

$D^c$ is just the open ball having $x$ as a center and $r$ as a radius. It's an open set so its complementary is closed. Thus $D$ is closed.

Suppose now that $y\in E$, then by definition :
$$y\in E \implies d(x,y)>r$$

Logically speaking, if $d(x,y)>r$ then $d(x,y)\geq r$

So $y\in E \implies y\in D$

And since $D$ is a closed set, we have the following property :
$$ D \text{  is a closed set} \iff \bar{D}=D$$

So D is a closed set, and it's equal to its closure, and since $y\in D$ then

$$y\in \bar{D}$$

Comment: For (b), would $D$ also be contained in the closure of $E$ in $A$?

Comment: @Kraftsman Yes. Since $\bar{E}=E\cup \partial E$ where $\partial E$ is the set of the elements in the boundaries of E, i.e, elements which satisfy $d(x,y)=r$. So we get that $\bar{E}=D$. Two equal sets means each set is included in the other, which yields $D \subset \bar{E}$.

Answer (score 1):

$D$ is closed in $A$. If $r = 0$, then $D = A$ which is closed by default. If $r > 0$, then we can prove $D$ is closed as follows. If $y_0 \in A$ is a limit point in $D$, then there is a sequence $(y_n)$ in $D$ which converges to $x_0$. If $\varepsilon > 0$ is small enough that $\varepsilon < r$, then we can choose sufficiently large $N$ so that $n \geq N$ implies that $d(y_n, y_0) < \varepsilon$. The condition on $\varepsilon$ ensures that $d(x,y_n) - d(y_n, y_0) > r - \varepsilon > 0$ so that the absolute value can be removed. Hence, by the reverse triangle inequality $$d(x, y_0) \geq |d(x, y_n) - d(y_n, y_0)| = d(x,y_n) - d(y_n, y_0) > r - \varepsilon$$ which proves that $d(x, y_0) \geq r$ so that $y_0 \in D$ (since $\varepsilon$ can be made arbitrarily small). Thus $D$ contains all its limit points so it is closed.

Since $D$ is closed, it is its own closure. Moreover, if $y \in A$ so that $d(x,y) > r$, then in particular $d(x,y) \geq r$ so that $y \in D$. Thus $A \subseteq D$ which proves (b).

Comment: So both $D$ are closed in $A$ and $E$ is in the closure then?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what Daniel Apsley just said!  Another way of seeing that D is closed- It's complement is {(x,y)| d(x,y)< r} which is clearly an open set.  The complement of an open set is a closed set. For the second one, E is a subset of D so even if it weren't closed, E would be a subset of its closure since any set is subset of its own closure.

Comment: @user247327 Sorry for the late response. Would $D$ then also be contained in the closure of $E$ in $A$?